# I'm trying to use route group in next.js App router. How should I declare a public not-found component?

Tags: next.js13, app-router

Currently, the folder structure has been created like this within the app folder.

In addition, I would like to render not-found.tsx when entering the 404 path. What should I do?

Even if I write app/not-found.tsx, it is not rendered.

(main)/not-found.tsx is also not applicable.

[image]